# Migrating to NativeScript 7

Tags: nativescript

I'm migrating a typescript/angular based NativeScript project over to the latest version of NativeScript, and am running into an issue. Before, I was using the tns-platform-declarations plugin (https://preview.npmjs.com/package/tns-platform-declarations) so I could get intellisense (I'm using VS Code) for things like UITextView and other native calls. But when updating my project, this module is removed from package.json. And if I add it back in, it says my project is not compatible with 7.x.

Do I just need to wait until the plugin is updated, or is there another way to get intellisense going, but still use NS 7.x?

Comment: I closed VS Code and reopened, and now I'm getting different behavior when running 'ns update'. So I'll keep plugging away at this - but leave it open in case anyone has an easier/better way to get intellisense working for native calls...

Answer (score 1):

Extending on Matthew's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63760551/10391569). Make sure you are including in your `tsconfig` the `references.d.ts` file, the one that points to either `tns-platform-declarations` or `@nativescript/types`, depending on your NativeScript version.

Answer (score 0):

When you migrate the project it will change your tns-platform-declaration to @nativescript/types

https://nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-7-announcement/

Comment: After a fresh start the next day I figured out that's what was happening. But my import statement still barfs: import { UITextView } from '@nativescript/types';  Am I missing something so that I can do something like: let uiTextView: UITextView;

Comment: Whenever that happens to me, I jus remove the import and then it should use the native Object